# AND operator to ignore null value

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with different field like  facility,type etc.I have a search form with type and facility field  and search button.When I am giving the input to both field  it gives me result but when i gives input to only one field it does not show any input.I am using AND operator in Where clause.

```
$facility=$_POST[facility];
$user=$_POST[user];
$type=$_POST[type];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tblfacility join tbluser on tbluser.id=tblfacility.user where facility = '".$facility."' AND type= '".$type."' " ;
$query = $dbh -> prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
$results=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
//echo "<prep>";
//echo "this is the final";
//print_r($row);
$cnt=1;
if($query->rowCount() > 0)
{
foreach($results as $result)
```

I think it is taking null value as some value and doing and operation and gives the result.How can i ignore null value in and operation

Comment: I think you missed a `$` in front of `type`.

Comment: 1. There is no JavaScript here 2. There is no HTML here 3. There is no AND here - the SQL WHERE clause uses OR.

Comment: you will not get any results, it means there's no matching empty type or empty facility on your table

Comment: @KIKOSoftware thanks I corrected that Still not working

Comment: Check emptiness of POST variables and create a query based on that.

Comment: @ϻᴇᴛᴀʟ how can i overcome this problem

Comment: question, is what are you trying to do? get facilities with default type or either way? or...

Comment: @ϻᴇᴛᴀʟI got your point but i am not able to think beyond this

Comment: BEWARE, this code is wide open to SQL injection: you are concatenating user inputs and sending them directly to the database.

Answer (score -1):

```
$wheres = [];
if (!empty($_POST['facility'])) {
    $wheres[] = "facility = '" . $_POST['facility'] . "'";
}
if (!empty($_POST['type'])) {
    $wheres[] = "type= '" . $_POST['type'] . "'";
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tblfacility join tbluser on tbluser.id=tblfacility.user";
if ($wheres) {
    $sql .= ' WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $wheres);
}
$query = $dbh -> prepare($sql);
```

Also, it's useless to **prepare** a query, if you don't have placeholders in it.